# CentOS 7 Installation: /boot naming scheme

Tags: linux, centos, boot, centos7

I'm currently going through an installation of CentOS7 on an HP MicroServer Gen7.  I'm installing onto a mirrored set of 240GB drives configured in hardware RAID1.

When configuring my partitioning scheme, I create `/boot` as a standard partition.  I'd usually expect this to be called `sda1`.  However, the CentOS7 installation gives it a name automatically: `pdc_ebjgddhjdi1`.  The "Name" field is also greyed out, refusing to allow me to alter it.

Has a naming scheme changed, similar to how network interfaces had their naming scheme changed?  The name seems somewhat random, so finding information on it doesn't seem to have helped.  The installer doesn't volunteer any information either.

I don't expect this to cause any problems, but the new name doesn't exactly roll off the tongue!  Out of sheer curiosity, is it possible to change it?  And what was wrong with the old name, anyhow?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're using _hardware_ RAID? That looks like a fake RAID device name.

Comment: I definitely configured a RAID1 set in the HP Array Configuration Utility, so I hope so!  I can't see any evidence of it *not* being configured correctly, but I'll be sure to check on reboot.  *(EDIT: Confirmed - RAID 1, 2 drives, status Functional)*

Comment: Thanks for your note Michael, you were on the money.  I've added an answer to expand on what I found out after going through with the install.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer this myself, since I've figured out what happened.

Turns out HP MicroServer Gen7 servers don't have *true* hardware RAID.  As Michael Hampton's instinct pointed out, the device name looked like a "Fake RAID" device name.  The CentOS installer realised this somehow and when I selected the disk that was labelled with "BIOS RAID Set (mirror)", it went ahead and silently set up things with `dmraid`.

Every day's a schoolday, I guess.  I only noticed after issuing an `lsblk` command, spuriously:

```
root@yalson:~# lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
└─pdc_ebjgddhjdi        253:0    0 231.9G  0 dmraid
  ├─pdc_ebjgddhjdi1     253:1    0   512M  0 part   /boot
  └─pdc_ebjgddhjdi2     253:2    0  76.1G  0 part
    ├─VolGroup00-rootLV 253:3    0    32G  0 lvm    /
    ├─VolGroup00-swapLV 253:4    0     4G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
    ├─VolGroup00-varLV  253:5    0     8G  0 lvm    /var
    ├─VolGroup00-homeLV 253:6    0    32G  0 lvm    /home
    └─VolGroup00-srvLV  253:7    0   128M  0 lvm    /srv
sdb                       8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
└─pdc_ebjgddhjdi        253:0    0 231.9G  0 dmraid
  ├─pdc_ebjgddhjdi1     253:1    0   512M  0 part   /boot
  └─pdc_ebjgddhjdi2     253:2    0  76.1G  0 part
    ├─VolGroup00-rootLV 253:3    0    32G  0 lvm    /
    ├─VolGroup00-swapLV 253:4    0     4G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
    ├─VolGroup00-varLV  253:5    0     8G  0 lvm    /var
    ├─VolGroup00-homeLV 253:6    0    32G  0 lvm    /home
    └─VolGroup00-srvLV  253:7    0   128M  0 lvm    /srv
```

It's all out the box stuff, and it did it all without mentioning.  Also, nice of the installer to not add the rest of the space in my mirrored set into the VG by default.

I ended up extending it with the following:

```
parted /dev/mapper/pdc_ebjgddhjdi
(parted) mkpart primary 3 100%
(parted) set 3 lvm on

# partition table couldn't be re-read, so reboot it is
reboot

# add it to lvm
pvcreate /dev/mapper/pdc_ebjgddhjdi3
vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/mapper/pdc_ebjgddhjdi3
```

Then, the usual filesystem-y stuff.  Anyways, hope this helps out someone else who might be confused by the whole thing.